# How to only show a navbar when the user is scrolling

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I made a navbar using react/next.js, and I only want to show it when the user is scrolling. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it. Below is my following code for the navbar:

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const [stickyClass, setStickyClass] = useState('relative');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
    };
  }, []);

  const stickNavbar = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let windowHeight = window.scrollY;
      windowHeight > 300 ? setStickyClass('fixed top-0 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 z-50 px-6 py-4 mt-8 border border-border w-96 bg-nav rounded-full') : setStickyClass('relative');
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav className='top-0 left-0 items-center justify-between w-full p-8 mv:hidden md:flex'>
        <div className='flex items-center cursor-pointer'>
          <Image className='w-6 h-6' src={home} alt='home icon' />
          <span className='text-paragraph font-poppins ml-2 hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Hogwarts</span>
        </div>
        <div className={`flex items-center text-paragraph w-72 justify-between font-poppins cursor-pointer ${stickyClass}`}>
          <Link href="#projects" className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Projects</Link>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>About</span>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Writing</span>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Tools</span>
        </div>
        <button className='bg-button p-3 rounded-full text-header text-sm border border-border shadow-btn font-poppins tracking-wide '>
          Contact
        </button>
      </nav>
      <MobileButton open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <MobileMenu open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the `navHeight` and then apply the sticky class there.
Here is a probable implementation.

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const [stickyClass, setStickyClass] = useState('relative');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const navRef = useRef(null);
  const timerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
    };
  }, []);

  const stickNavbar = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let windowHeight = window.scrollY;
      let navHeight = navRef.current.offsetHeight;

      windowHeight > navHeight ? setStickyClass('fixed top-0 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 z-50 px-6 py-4 mt-8 border border-border w-96 bg-nav rounded-full') : setStickyClass('relative');

      if (timerRef.current !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
      }
      timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setStickyClass("relative");
      }, 500);

    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav ref={navRef} className='top-0 left-0 items-center justify-between w-full p-8 mv:hidden md:flex'>
        <div className='flex items-center cursor-pointer'>
          <Image className='w-6 h-6' src={home} alt='home icon' />
          <span className='text-paragraph font-poppins ml-2 hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Hogwarts</span>
        </div>
        <div className={`flex items-center text-paragraph w-72 justify-between font-poppins cursor-pointer ${stickyClass}`}>
          <Link href="#projects" className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Projects</Link>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>About</span>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Writing</span>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Tools</span>
        </div>
        <button className='bg-button p-3 rounded-full text-header text-sm border border-border shadow-btn font-poppins tracking-wide '>
          Contact
        </button>
      </nav>
      <MobileButton open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <MobileMenu open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: The nav still doesn't disappear when the user stops scrolling @Sitaf

Comment: @maxheezy's, I've updated the code. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

try with below,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useWindowScroll } from "react-use";

export default function Navbar() {
  const [stickyClass, setStickyClass] = useState("relative");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const { scrollY } = useWindowScroll();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", stickNavbar);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", stickNavbar);
    };
  }, []);

  const stickNavbar = () => {
    if (scrollY > 300) {
      setStickyClass("fixed top-0 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 z-50 px-6 py-4 mt-8 border border-border w-96 bg-nav rounded-full");
    } else {
      setStickyClass("relative");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav className={`top-0 left-0 items-center justify-between w-full p-8 mv:hidden md:flex ${stickyClass}`}>
        <div className='flex items-center cursor-pointer'>
          <Image className='w-6 h-6' src={home} alt='home icon' />
          <span className='text-paragraph font-poppins ml-2 hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Hogwarts</span>
        </div>
        <div className='flex items-center text-paragraph w-72 justify-between font-poppins cursor-pointer'>
          <Link href="#projects" className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Projects</Link>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>About</span>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Writing</span>
          <span className='hover:text-theme transition duration-150 ease-in'>Tools</span>
        </div>
        <button className='bg-button p-3 rounded-full text-header text-sm border border-border shadow-btn font-poppins tracking-wide '>
          Contact
        </button>
      </nav>
      <MobileButton open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <MobileMenu open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think react-use is a real thing

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use